# Computer crashing when using python tools in same script

Tags: python, multithreading, ffmpeg, crash, speech-recognition

I am attempting to use the speech recognition toolkit VOSK and the speech diarization package Resemblyzer to transcibe audio and then identify the speakers in the audio.

**Tools:**

https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api
https://github.com/resemble-ai/Resemblyzer

I can do both things individually but run into issues when trying to do them when running the one python script.

**I used the following guide when setting up the diarization system:**

https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/who-spoke-when-build-your-own-speaker-diarization-module-from-scratch-e7d725ee279

**Computer specs are as follows:**

Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz, 3912 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
32GB RAM

The following is my code, I am not to sure if using threading is appropriate or if I even implemented it correctly, how can I best optimize this code as to achieve the results I am looking for and not crash.

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
from pydub import AudioSegment
import json
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import datetime
from resemblyzer import preprocess_wav, VoiceEncoder
from pathlib import Path
from resemblyzer.hparams import sampling_rate
from spectralcluster import SpectralClusterer
import threading
import queue
import gc



def recognition(queue, audio, FRAME_RATE):

    model = Model("Vosk_Models/vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15")

    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, FRAME_RATE)
    rec.SetWords(True)

    rec.AcceptWaveform(audio.raw_data)
    result = rec.Result()

    transcript = json.loads(result)#["text"]

    #return transcript
    queue.put(transcript)



def diarization(queue, audio):

    wav = preprocess_wav(audio)
    encoder = VoiceEncoder("cpu")
    _, cont_embeds, wav_splits = encoder.embed_utterance(wav, return_partials=True, rate=16)
    print(cont_embeds.shape)

    clusterer = SpectralClusterer(
        min_clusters=2,
        max_clusters=100,
        p_percentile=0.90,
        gaussian_blur_sigma=1)

    labels = clusterer.predict(cont_embeds)

    def create_labelling(labels, wav_splits):

        times = [((s.start + s.stop) / 2) / sampling_rate for s in wav_splits]
        labelling = []
        start_time = 0

        for i, time in enumerate(times):
            if i > 0 and labels[i] != labels[i - 1]:
                temp = [str(labels[i - 1]), start_time, time]
                labelling.append(tuple(temp))
                start_time = time
            if i == len(times) - 1:
                temp = [str(labels[i]), start_time, time]
                labelling.append(tuple(temp))

        return labelling

    #return
    labelling = create_labelling(labels, wav_splits)
    queue.put(labelling)



def identify_speaker(queue1, queue2):

    transcript = queue1.get()
    labelling = queue2.get()

    for speaker in labelling:

        speakerID = speaker[0]
        speakerStart = speaker[1]
        speakerEnd = speaker[2]

        result = transcript['result']
        words = [r['word'] for r in result if speakerStart < r['start'] < speakerEnd]
        #return
        print("Speaker",speakerID,":",' '.join(words), "\n")





def main():

    queue1 = queue.Queue()
    queue2 = queue.Queue()

    FRAME_RATE = 16000
    CHANNELS = 1

    podcast = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Podcast_Audio/Film-Release-Clip.mp3")
    podcast = podcast.set_channels(CHANNELS)
    podcast = podcast.set_frame_rate(FRAME_RATE)

    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=recognition, args=(queue1, podcast, FRAME_RATE))
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=diarization, args=(queue2, podcast))
    third_thread = threading.Thread(target=identify_speaker, args=(queue1, queue2))

    first_thread.start()
    first_thread.join()
    gc.collect()

    second_thread.start()
    second_thread.join()
    gc.collect()

    third_thread.start()
    third_thread.join()
    gc.collect()

    # transcript = recognition(podcast,FRAME_RATE)
    #
    # labelling = diarization(podcast)
    #
    # print(identify_speaker(transcript, labelling))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I say crash I mean  everything freezes, I have to hold down the power button on the desktop and turn it back on again. No blue/blank screen, just frozen in my IDE looking at my code. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the crash? Does Python give you an error traceback or does your system stop responding/bluescreen/etc? Please be more specific.

Comment: Apologies @b-remmelzwaal, everything freezes, I have to hold down the power button on the desktop and turn it back on again. No blue/blank screen, just frozen in my IDE looking at my code.

Comment: I would recommend updating the body to include that. Is it possible for you to step through the code using a debugger and find out which part is causing the hanging?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal trying this but being met with crashes after the recognition function runs. Have set breakpoints at every function and at the creation of three the threads but everything stops dead after I have transcribed the audio. Admittedly I dont have much experience with debugging but I dont believe any warning signs are being thrown up before the crash.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I went back and changed how I called the second function, did it this time without the threading and it appears to be hanging at "wav = preprocess_wav(audio)" when I am stepping through my code.

Comment: I'm looking at the [`preprocess_wav` function](https://github.com/resemble-ai/Resemblyzer/blob/master/resemblyzer/audio.py) and noticed it expects either a path or Numpy array, and you seem to pass whatever AudioSegment returns. Is that correct?

Comment: The issue is related to the audio processing I was doing with pydubs AudioSegment specifically when I was setting audio channels and frame rate, turned out it wasnt returning the desired type which was causing issues when I was passing the result into preprocess_wav, which as you mentioned looks for a Numpy array. Thanks very much for the insight @BRemmelzwaal

Comment: Really odd how that just freezes your machine though, maybe Python doesn't expect an entire mp3 to be passed as an argument. Glad I could be of help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Pydubs AudioSegment was not returning a suitable type for the Resembylzer function preprocess_wav.

```
podcast = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Podcast_Audio/Film-Release-Clip.mp3")
```

preprocess_wav instead requires a Numpy Array / Path.

```
audio_file_path = 'Podcast_Audio/WAV-Film-Release-Clip.wav'
wav_fpath = Path(audio_file_path)
wav = preprocess_wav(wav_fpath)
```

Additionally preprocess_wav functionality can be achieved using  *Librosa*  if desired.

```
import librosa

def preprocess_wav(waveform, sr):

   waveform = librosa.resample(waveform, orig_sr=sr, target_sr=16000)
   waveform = waveform.astype(np.float32) / np.max(np.abs(waveform))

   return waveform

waveform, sr = librosa.load('Podcast_Audio/WAV-Film-Release-Clip.wav')
wav = preprocess_wav(waveform, sr)
```